# Авторизация (как на модемах)

Tags: авторизация, html, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
----Вопрос 1----
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как делается [авторизация в окне alert](http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0000/1218/62658/141112/0b36e08cc2.jpg), самый простой пример, часто на модемах делают такую авторизацию.  
И вообще, как она правильно называется?

----Вопрос 2---- 
Подскажите, пожалуйста можно ли авторизоваться в данной форме без использования окна, например, через GET запрос или ещё как-то?  
Например, на телефоне окно не отображается, можно ли как-то авторизоваться или нет?

Comment: http://htmlweb.ru/service/htpasswd.php

по поводу второго вопроса - хз

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы браузер запросил логин и пароль в alert'е, необходимо, чтобы сервер вернул ответ с кодом 401 - Not Authorized и хедером `WWW-Authenticate` со значением, указывающим требуемый тип авторизации (например, Basic).

Для осуществления авторизации без необходимости вводить логин и пароль, необходимо в запросе послать хедер `Authorization`. В самом простом случае хедер будет выглядеть так: `Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==`. Здесь `dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==` - это логин и пароль пользователя, записанные через двоеточие и закодированные в [base64](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). В JavaScript такую строку можно получить вызовом функции `btoa('user:password')`.

[Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)